# How to set a chart's X axis name and Y axis name?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, flex4

In Flex how can I set a custom name (string) for the X axis and Y axis titles of a chart ?

(Horizontal Axis and Vertical Axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and assign an object that implements `IAxis` for `horizontalAxis`& `verticalAxis` property of a chart. Usually this means either `mx.charts.CategoryAxis` or `mx.charts.LinearAxis`.

```
var vAxis:LinearAxis = new LinearAxis();
vAxis.title = "WhateverYouWant";            
chart.verticalAxis = vAxis;
```